# How to set Json PropertyNamingStrategy on Controller Response time

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, naming-conventions

I have a `REST` controller that returns an `Object`. I want to set the `PropertyNamingStrategy` at the time of controller action response. For instance, based on who calls this controller, I wanna respond by sending a `Camel case` naming convention, and in another case return a `Snake case` naming style. I can use an object mapper in my controller action but that only returns a `String` type. I still want my `Object` type but with different naming convention. Any suggestions?

I'm using `Springboot 2.x`.

Comment: So, you have a method signature `public Object method(...)` and you want to return `POJO` object, not a `String`. Can you for example return `Map<>` instead of `POJO`? To return `JSON` payloads with different `PropertyNamingStrategy`-ies and using the same `ObjectMapper` instance would be unpredictable, I guess. So, probably, you need to configure few of them and use appropriate when needed.

Comment: I want to return the Object which automatically will be converted to JSON output when controller action returns. But the attribute names are in camel case, I want them to be snake case in certain scenarios. So I wanna dynamically override the naming strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this problem. I extended the naming strategy like:

```
 public class GetSnakeCaseSetCamelCaseNamingStrategy
    extends PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

  @Override
  public String translate(String propertyName) {
    return propertyName;
  }

  @Override
  public String nameForGetterMethod(
      MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {
    return PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE.nameForGetterMethod(config, method, defaultName);
  }

  @Override
  public String nameForSetterMethod(
      MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {

    return PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE.nameForSetterMethod(config, method, defaultName);
  }
}
```

Then annotated my Pojo with my own naming strategy and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If your rest controller returns a POJO and that POJO needs to be converted to JSON with different naming strategy eg SNAKE_CASE for a given type of user and CAMEL_CASE for other type of user based on your requirement, then you need to create your own HttpMessageConverter and register it with Spring.

1. Your Custom HttpMessageConverter looks like this:-

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.util.TypeUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

class CustomJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    private static final ObjectMapper snakeCaseObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

    ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        MediaType contentType = outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
        JsonEncoding encoding = getJsonEncoding(contentType);
        //Note:- Get the appropriate ObjectMapper and use them to write Object to Json string accordingly
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper(outputMessage);
        JsonGenerator generator = objectMapper.getFactory().createGenerator(outputMessage.getBody(), encoding);
        try {
            writePrefix(generator, object);

            Class<?> serializationView = null;
            FilterProvider filters = null;
            Object value = object;
            JavaType javaType = null;
            if (object instanceof MappingJacksonValue) {
                MappingJacksonValue container = (MappingJacksonValue) object;
                value = container.getValue();
                serializationView = container.getSerializationView();
                filters = container.getFilters();
            }
            if (type != null && TypeUtils.isAssignable(type, value.getClass())) {
                javaType = getJavaType(type, null);
            }
            ObjectWriter objectWriter;
            if (serializationView != null) {
                objectWriter = objectMapper.writerWithView(serializationView);
            } else if (filters != null) {
                objectWriter = objectMapper.writer(filters);
            } else {
                objectWriter = objectMapper.writer();
            }
            if (javaType != null && javaType.isContainerType()) {
                objectWriter = objectWriter.forType(javaType);
            }
            SerializationConfig config = objectWriter.getConfig();
            if (contentType != null && contentType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) &&
                    config.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)) {
                objectWriter = objectWriter.with(this.ssePrettyPrinter);
            }
            objectWriter.writeValue(generator, value);

            writeSuffix(generator, object);
            generator.flush();

        } catch (InvalidDefinitionException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageConversionException("Type definition error: " + ex.getType(), ex);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + ex.getOriginalMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = outputMessage.getHeaders();
        /** TODO:- Check in responseHeaders if it is a specific user demanding
         * response with PropertyNamingStrategy as PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE
         * For eg:- you can have a header with name- jsonNamingStrategy=SNAKE_CASE or any default value or empty
         * Based on jsonNamingStrategy you can decide if user wants response in SnakeCase or default one
         * Return appropriately based on your check. For now returning snakeCaseObjectMapper
         **/
        return snakeCaseObjectMapper;
    }
}
```

2. And you need to register your CustomJackson2HttpMessageConverter with Spring as:-

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new CustomJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        //Replace the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter with the CustomJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        converters.replaceAll(it -> it instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ? customJackson2HttpMessageConverter : it);
        if (!converters.contains(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter)) {
            converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Similarly if you want to handle the scenario where you want to parse JSON with different naming strategy to POJO, then you can override method readInternal() of the CustomJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

Comment: How can I only apply this strategy to a specific controller? I don't want all controllers act this way. Also I'm using SpringBoot, not SpringMVC.

Comment: This will work for SpringBoot as well. However if you don't want to do this for all controller, then you can make use of @ControllerAdvice or Spring AOP. May be you can have a look here:-  1. https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/06/08/filtering-responses-in-spring-mvc/ and 2. https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing.html